# Eclipse no longer can auto import java Classes

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

A few days ago my eclipse stopped being able to auto import classes. So usually when I have a class I'm using, like BufferedReader, that I need to import I simply hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and the imports magically appear.  But now, basic imports like List or Scanner just sit there all squiggly and red.  I have the 1.6JRE included as part of my project, and when I manually import them they will then work.

This is a huge annoyance and time sink now.  I'm open to any suggestions to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you check to the shortcut keys to make sure it wasn't changed?  Window>Prefences>General>Keys?

Comment: So the key mapping is still the same, and the restart didn't work.  But! the good news is Jim's second suggestion works.  Recreating the project from the source fixed the problem.  Man that was annoying, thank you!

Comment: As an aside, can you make your comment an answer I can mark Jim?  Your suggestion works, but don't know how to give you credit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen this behavior before. Sometimes just closing and reopening Eclipse resolves it. Sometimes I have had to recreate the project from the source, which can be painful if you have a lot of dependencies and you're not using Maven. You should also do a File/Refresh at the top level to make sure you're in sync with the filesystem

Comment: I had to recreate the whole project, because I had imported an existent one

Answer (score 6):

1. Try restoring the default options in 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced'.
2. If it does not work, try to create a new workspace and it may solve your problem

Hope it helps!

Comment: As the problem is now gone I can't test to make sure this works.  But if it ever happens in the future I will try this first! a bit easier than recreating a project.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project. I fixed mine by cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, cleaning just a project didn't fix but clean all project did.